# iOS - dismissModalViewController not working

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

A tap on `ShowWebsiteButton` on `MainViewController` shows a Website on `WebViewController`.
A tap on `CloseWebViewButton` on `WebViewController` should dismiss the `WebViewController` and show me the `MainViewController` again. NOTE: `MainViewController` opens the `WebViewController` successfully and the website gets loaded, I'm just unable to get back to `MainViewController`.

MainViewController.h

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) WebViewController *webViewController;
```

MainViewController.m

```
   - (IBAction)showWebsiteButton:(id)sender {

        NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.apple.com"

        self.webViewController.delegate = self;

        self.webViewController.websiteName = fullURL;

        self.webViewController.serviceName = @"Apple";

        [self.view addSubview:self.webViewController.view];
    }


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
             [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

WebViewController.h

```
@property id <UIWebViewDelegate>delegate;
```

WebViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)closeBtnTapped:(id)sender {

   [self.delegate webViewDidFinishLoad:self.webView];
}
```

Comment: Gets (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView ever called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using presentModalViewController in your code. You are just adding the webView as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

You assign the `UIWebViewDelegate` in the `WebViewController` to the instance of the `WebViewController`. Therefor your `MainViewController` is not listening to the `UIWebView` delegate methods.

However your are not presenting your `WebViewController` with `presentModalViewController` method.

In the `closeBtnTapped` just call the `dismissModalViewController` method and send it to `self`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[self.view addSubview:self.webViewController.view];`
use `[self presentModalViewCOntroller:webViewController animated:yes];`

then the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear one thing. As ashokbabuy is right.
Whenever you use the presentModalViewController in your code,Just Remember the Viewcontroller you are presenting in current controller, its a good practice to dismiss in that presented controller.

I mean if you are presenting WebViewcontroller in MainController. Its a good practise to dismiss it in WebViewController closebuttontap event.

So it would be just simple code as follows

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```